# Is it good practice to use a static class/methods when there is only one resource (e..g, Kinect sensor)

Tags: c#, oop, kinect

I am writing a C# program that records and processes video for the Microsoft Kinect. I have created a `KinectManager` class which checks the state of the sensor, and does things like activating, deactivating, and recording the color stream.

Since there can only be one Kinect sensor plugged in, I will always only need one instance of the `KinectManager` class every time the program is run. In this case, is it good practice to make the class or its methods static?

Comment: Generally state should not be static. This will make it very hard to test. An alternative is [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Answer (score 2):

While static methods could be handy, keep in mind statics aren't object oriented design. E.g. inheritance won't work and static classes can't implement interfaces.

Also you get more coupled code as it's more work to to replace static calls than passing another instance.

Static methods are better when not dealing with state (e.g. `ToUpperCase(string)`) - as  @Wazner also mentioned.

In this case you could use the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), this will ensure there is only one instance.

For example:

```
public class KinectManager {

    // instance, another option is to make it lazy, but be aware if it's needs to be threadsafe. 
    private static KinectManager _instance = new KinectManager();

    //private ctor to ensure it won't be created outside this class .
    private KinectManager () {}

    // The instance
    public static KinectManager Instance {
        get { return _instance ;}
    }
}
```

But be aware that the [singleton pattern is overused in the real world](https://aabs.wordpress.com/2007/03/08/singleton-%E2%80%93-the-most-overused-pattern/). If something goes wrong when you have two instances, then singleton is a great way to ensure that this won't happen. But if two instances are OK, then maybe the singleton pattern is over-design.